# Inode Timestamp Plus/Minus Interpretation

Tags: ext4, timestamps, inode, stat

What does `+0200` mean after the Access/Modify/Change timestamps?

```
File: task-system.md
  Size: 197             Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 14155787    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     tom)   Gid: ( 1000/     tom)
Access: 2018-08-26 15:19:07.047602175 +0200
Modify: 2018-08-26 15:18:59.531538750 +0200
Change: 2018-08-26 15:18:59.535538783 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s the timezone. The times are given in a UTC+2 timezone (the timestamps are stored [as seconds since the Unix epoch](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Timestamps), and translated to whatever the current user’s timezone is for display).